# what is "password aging limits"?

Tags: user-management

It seems like **password aging limit** is responsible for regular change of password.But my questions are,

1. What exactly it is and which password does it change?
2. How can I configure it to change the password regularly, say every week.

If necessary, note that I use Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/105040/how-do-i-force-a-user-to-change-the-password-periodically

Comment: I found this link. It may help you:https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/how-does-changing-your-password-every-90-days-increase-security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Password aging is a mechanism that allows the system to enforce a
>   certain lifetime for passwords. While this may be moderately
>   inconvenient for users, it ensures that passwords are changed
>   occasionally, which is a good security practice. Most Linux
>   distributions do not enable password aging by default, but it's very
>   easy to enable.

By editing /etc/login.defs, you can specify a few parameters to set the default settings for password aging:

```
PASS_MAX_DAYS   99999
PASS_MIN_DAYS   0
PASS_WARN_AGE   7
```

change These values as you want. change 9999 to 7 to enforce all users to change their password every 7 days.

[source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-set-default-password-expiry-for-all-new-users.html)

Answer (score 7):

It is probaly called "password age limit". You can set it with the `x` option from `passwd`

```
passwd -x 7 $USER
```

will force you to issue a new password for the current user every 7 days.

---

[From the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/passwd.1.html)

> -x, --maxdays MAX_DAYS
>
> Set the maximum number of days a password remains valid. After MAX_DAYS, the password is required to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `PASS_MAX_DAYS` parameter in `/etc/login.defs` allows you to force passwords to expire once they reach a defined age. It is recommended that the `PASS_MAX_DAYS` parameter be set to less than or equal to 90 days.